# Conditionally Colouring Bars in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is some code for a simple example dataframe and plot. I'm wondering how to conditionally colour the bars. I'm familiar with `scale_fill_manual` to manually colour the bars, but what if I wanted `"Satisfied"` in the `2016` facet to be a different colour if it's a lower percentage than `"Satisfied"` in `2015`. Perhaps a red warning border or a different colour, like orange (just for an example).

This isn't the best example, but if I had a plot of year-over-year top box scores, this would be useful to have bars change colour if they dropped below a certain percentage. I tried playing around with `"colour = ifelse(Perc < 60, "orange", "green"` combinations, but couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure how to structure the `ifelse` statement or where to place it within the ggplot code.

```
Year<-c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016)

Service<-c("Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied",
           "Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied")

df <- data.frame(Year, Service)

library(dplyr)
df.prop <- df %>%
            count(Year, Service) %>%
            mutate(Perc = prop.table(n))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.prop, aes(x = Service, y = Perc, fill = Service)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
       geom_text(aes(label = percent(Perc)), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                 vjust = 1.5, size = 3) +
       scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
       facet_grid( ~ Year)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be easiest to add a new variable to your data frame:

```
df.prop$colour <- ifelse(df.prop$Service == "Satisfied" & df.prop$Perc < 0.6, "orange", NA)
```

Then you can do:

```
ggplot(df.prop, aes(x = Service, y = Perc, fill = Service, colour=colour)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(Perc)), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            vjust = 1.5, size = 3, colour="black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  facet_grid( ~ Year) +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

If you want to change the fill based on the condition you can do:

```
df.prop$fill <- ifelse(df.prop$Service == "Satisfied" & df.prop$Perc < 0.6, "orange", ifelse(df.prop$Service == "Satisfied" & df.prop$Perc >= 0.6, "#00BFC4", "#F8766D"))

ggplot(df.prop, aes(x = Service, y = Perc, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(Perc)), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            vjust = 1.5, size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  facet_grid( ~ Year) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great. Just one follow-up question, the answer allows me to add the coloured border, but how would I change the actual bar colour to orange instead of just the outline?

Comment: How can I get a legend for the 2nd diagram?